# Button on a ListView - using MVVM

Tags: listview, mvvm, button, controls

I have a button on a listview control. I have bound this control to one of the command on the base class of the ViewModel class. If I place a button outside of the listview it works fine with the same command. But the command does not get fired when I place it on the listview.

can you think of a reason????

Below is the snippet:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AObject}" Margin="20" MaxHeight="200">
            <ListView.DataContext>
                <local:MyViewModel/>
            </ListView.DataContext>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Run ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Job ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=JID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Run Description">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=OpenScCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Edit">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button  Command="{Binding ShowItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RID}" Content="_Edit email run" IsDefault="False"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the button is in the `ListViewItem`, so it inherits the DataContext of the item that contains it. Here's how you can bind to the DataContext of the `ListView` itself:

```
<Button  Command="{Binding ShowItemCommand}" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" ...
```

As a side note: depending on what the command does, it might be better to put it in the ViewModel of the items

Comment: on the view model of the items?! the items represent *data*, not logic. putting commands there is wrong imho.

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought so. I could have implemented the ViewModellocator approach but this one turned out to more faster.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the button inside the listview it gets a new DataContext - it gets the DataContext of the current item in the list, and therefor it loses the original DataContext.

The best solution to this is using [ViewModelLocator](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ViewModelLocator)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a little less code..

```
<Button Command="{Binding ShowItemCommand}">
    <Button.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Button.DataContext>
 </Button>
```